# Word 2016, how to align overflowing text on multiple lines in a list?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, list

I have the following:

word misaligned text:

[image]

I want to achieve something like the following:

[image: word aligned text]

without all the mess of spaces and tabs (thats how I got the top one).

Is there a "proper" way to do this, without messy tabs and spaces?

Just realised the last time I used word was in 2008...

Comment: [Create a hanging indent](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-hanging-indent-7bdfb86a-c714-41a8-ac7a-3782a91ccad5)

Comment: That doesn't work on a list. It drags the entire text forward.